# Windows 10 - don't show 'wrong pin' when the inputted pin is the length of my pin

Tags: windows-10, pin

I like the pin option in Windows 10 for logging in quickly. I have a few security issues with it though. My pin is *x* digits long. Whenever the user inputs *x* digits it tries to log-in with the inputted pin. I don't want the computer to try the pin until I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in order not to reveal how long the pin is. This makes the pin more secure.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

From the Start menu, click Settings. Go to Account settings. Then Click Sign-in options. Enable the Password option. This is a workaround because pin does not require enter to be pressed. But password requires. But you can still use your pin to log in, not the password. So you have to manually press Enter each time you log in.

Comment: So I have to set my pin as my 'password'?

Comment: No you don't need to change, it is working for me